# HortonWorks Sandbox 2.5 yum install python-pip not working

Tags: python, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to install python pip on the virtual image for HDP 2.5. But it fails throwing an error.

[root@sandbox ~]# yum install python-pip

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                          |  15 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * epel: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: mirror.ilumno.com
 * updates: mirrors.oit.uci.edu
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6/repodata/7fcacadb44b1a860fb704795c187f549103e855a0a93ed31293a0b270a9022b4-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 MCPMediaTypeBlocked"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: failure: repodata/7fcacadb44b1a860fb704795c187f549103e855a0a93ed31293a0b270a9022b4-primary.sqlite.bz2 from HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[root@sandbox ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl, priorities
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                          |  12 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * epel: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: mirror.ilumno.com
 * updates: mirrors.oit.uci.edu
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos6/repodata/7fcacadb44b1a860fb704795c187f549103e855a0a93ed31293a0b270a9022b4-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 MCPMediaTypeBlocked"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

Error: failure: repodata/7fcacadb44b1a860fb704795c187f549103e855a0a93ed31293a0b270a9022b4-primary.sqlite.bz2 from HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a repository problem of Sandbox version 2.5.

You can solve it by running the following commands in root context:

```
[root@sandbox maria_dev]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]# cp sandbox.repo /tmp
[root@sandbox yum.repos.d]# rm sandbox.repo
```

Now you can try installing pip again and it should work fine:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# yum install python-pip
```